# Compatibility of using Syncfusion JS Component in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I am using trail version and checking the compatibility of using a 3rd party UI component with Salesforce such as Syncfusion.

Yes, I am aware that we can use 3rd party libraries but we want to check it directly since these 3rd party component mostly create elements at runtime using "document.createElement". But, as per the standard of Salesforce LWC, we could not use these in LWC.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/security_locker_dom

But, while checking by creating LWC as per the below link,
https://sfdcmonkey.com/2019/02/15/lightning-web-component-deploy-org/

I am getting the following error while connecting to Salesforce account
[image]

[image]

http://localhost:1717/OauthRedirect?code=aPrxUHjncL9lYc6SMdS0RVSZBqupHf6OkmRawX05G0pCV6_N71OZdj8QHFjYf65stphf.M5U9g%3D%3D&state=e8101516be24

While searching in the internet, I found that trail version did not have the API support.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326486&type=1&mode=1

Please suggest me to connect my local salesforce project with high priority since my trail ends in 8 days,

Else, please let us know whether we can use the Syncfusion in LWC components that you can refer from the below links.

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/introduction/
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/

Comment: While you get the answer which may take some time, you can get the community version of sync fusion products to stop worrying about the trial expiry at https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense here for personal use.

Comment: @manjit5190 Syncfusion Licensing is not an issue here. My trail of Salesforce ends in couple of days. Third party component developers like Syncfusion use document class extensively for manipulating element dynamically. So, I decide to check the compatibility of Salesforce with Syncfusion with Salesforce trail account.